# SBT ScalaTest dependency resolving

Tags: sbt

In **build.sbt**.

```
resolvers += "Repo1" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"

resolvers += "Repo2" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.11" % "test",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest_2.11" % "2.1.5" % "test"
)


scalacOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Yrangepos")

// Read here for optional dependencies:
// http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html#Dependencies

resolvers ++= Seq("snapshots", "releases").map(Resolver.sonatypeRepo)
```

Symptoms:

- `Specs2` is resolvable, **[scalatest](http://www.scalatest.org/download) is not**

> org.scalatest#scalatest_2.11_2.10;2.1.5: not found

- With `Maven`, using the same repositories - everything works perfectly.

Question:

- What's wrong with `sbt`, why does it complain all the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.11" % "test",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.5" % "test"
)
```

in your `libraryDependencies` (note the removed `_2.11`).

The reason is that `%%` will append a correct suffix for you, depending on the Scala version you're using. You can read more in [Getting the right Scala version with %%](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html#getting-the-right-scala-version-with).

> If you use groupID %% artifactID % revision rather than groupID %
>   artifactID % revision (the difference is the double %% after the
>   groupID), sbt will add your project's Scala version to the artifact
>   name. This is just a shortcut.

The reason for it are publishing conventions, via SBT documentation:

> The underlying mechanism used to indicate which version of Scala a
>   library was compiled against is to append _ to the
>   library's name. For Scala 2.10.0 and later, the binary version is
>   used. For example, dispatch becomes dispatch_2.8.1 for the variant
>   compiled against Scala 2.8.1 and dispatch_2.10 when compiled against
>   2.10.0, 2.10.0-M1 or any 2.10.x version. This fairly simple approach allows interoperability with users of Maven, Ant and other build
>   tools.

You have added a Scala version yourself and SBT appended one extra, so your artifact name became `scalatest_2.11_2.10`, which doesn't exist - hence the error.